# Routing a single page application with multiple sub-applications

Tags: ember.js

I have two distinct applications inside of a main application "shell".

The main application handles login and contains an outlet for the sub application, e.g.

```
<header>
{{outlet}}
<footer>
```

The sub applications are just standard ember applications with their own namespace, routes, etc.

I would like to be able to wire them together like this

```
MainApp.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("login");
  this.route("sub1", SubApp1.Router);
  this.route("sub2", SubApp2.Router);
});

/login -> MainApp.LoginRoute
/sub1/foo -> SubApp1.FooRoute
/sub2/foo/bar -> SubApp2.FooBarRoute
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a fun idea, but nested applications aren't supported in this fashion.  Only 1 router can be in use at a time.  You could do a single application and share your router, but you'll have to make sure everything is in the same namespace, or use dependency injection of some sort to make sure all of the dependencies are available.

```
SubApp1.MyRouting = function() {
  this.route("foo");
}

SubApp2.MyRouting = function() {
  this.route("bar");
}
```

In MainApp

```
MainApp.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("login");
  this.route("sub1", SubApp1.MyRouting);
  this.route("sub2", SubApp2.MyRouting);
});
```

If SubApp is separate and alone in a page

```
SubApp1.Router.map(SubApp1.MyRouting);
```

Comment: I really want separate namespaces. Could I include SubApp1 and SubApp2 namespaces into the Main namespace using mixins? I don't need to deal with naming collisions.

Comment: Namespacing for the router (and a slew of other things) is far from defined (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1925).  Additionally the container looks up based on the current namespace, but will lookup based on a different namespace if there is a slash `namespace2/main`.  Unfortunately there aren't hooks for specifying which namespace to use for each portion in Ember (such as the router).

Comment: I ended up using a single router and aliasing the one namespace like `SubApp1 = SubApp2 = MainApp = Ember.Application.create()` just for the sake of organization.